# Configure NGINX + CloudFlare + SSL

Tags: ssl, nginx, https, ubuntu-16.04, cloudflare

SO...

I have a node application running on a server on port 8080 and I am trying to enabled it to work over SSL using NGINX and CloudFlare. Note the following...

1. My host is running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS
2. I am currently using CloudFlare's Universal SSL (free tier)
3. I have my test host DNS setup as test.company.com
4. I have copied the CloudFlare origin pull cert from [this](https://blog.cloudflare.com/protecting-the-origin-with-tls-authenticated-origin-pulls/) post to my test box's /etc/nginx/certs

...my previous NGINX configuration looked like...

```
server {
    listen 80;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
    }
}
```

...it now looks like...

```
# HTTP
server {
  listen 80;
  listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;
  return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

# HTTPS
server {
  listen 443;
  server_name test.company.com;

  ssl on;
  ssl_client_certificate /etc/nginx/certs/cloudflare.crt;
  ssl_verify_client on;
  ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
  ssl_ciphers EECDH+CHACHA20:EECDH+AES128:RSA+AES128:EECDH+AES256:RSA+AES256:EECDH+3DES:RSA+3DES:!MD5;
  ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

  location / {
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8080/;
    proxy_ssl_session_reuse off;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    proxy_redirect off;
  }
}
```

...I followed the example [here](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/204494148-Setting-up-NGINX-to-use-TLS-Authenticated-Origin-Pulls) and the link it provides [here](https://blog.cloudflare.com/protecting-the-origin-with-tls-authenticated-origin-pulls/) and I'm skeptical that everything above is required (I'm a minimalist). Whenever I run `sudo nginx -t` I still get errors around ssl_certificate and ssl_certificate_key not being specified. I cannot figure out how to download the require files from CloudFlare and from what I understand, I don't believe I should need to.

If I try to re-use the CloudFlare origin pull cert as both the ssl_certificate and ssl_certificate_key, I get the error `nginx: [emerg] SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey_file("/etc/nginx/certs/cloudflare.crt") failed (SSL: error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line:Expecting: ANY PRIVATE KEY error:140B0009:SSL routines:SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey_file:PEM lib)`

I am confident that it is possible to create my own self-signed certificate, but I am planning on using this strategy eventually to spin up production machines. Any help on pointing me in the right direction is much appreciated.

Comment: Using my own generated pem and key, it works. Using the files generated by CloudFlare, I have the same issue. Did you find what was wrong ?

Comment: @ClémentDuveau It has been a while since I was looking into this, but I think when you first create a CloudFlare distribution (or whatever it is called), the ssl_certificate_key is provided at that time, once... and that needs to be used with the certificate you can download from CloudFlare at any time. At the time I wrote this, I think I simply didn't have access to the original key file. I hope that helps, but again, I really am not sure.

Answer (score 12):

It looks like you're using Cloudflare's Origin CA service, nice!

The issue looks like you've put your SSL private key in the `ssl_client_certificate` attribute and not put your real SSL certificate in your configuration. Your Nginx SSL configuration should contain the following lines instead:

```
ssl_certificate         /path/to/your_certificate.pem;
ssl_certificate_key     /path/to/your_key.key;
```

Make sure SSL Certificate corresponds to the *.PEM* file with the correct contents, and the Certificate Key file contains the *.KEY* file with the correct contents too.

To generate a certificate with Origin CA, navigate to the Crypto section of the Cloudflare dashboard. From there, click the *Create Certificate* button in the *Origin Certificates* section. Once you complete the steps in the wizard, you will see a window which allows you to download both the certificate file and the key file. Make sure you put them in the correct files and install them on your web server.

[image: Cloudflare Origin CA Certificate and Key]

Further reading:

- [How to install an Origin CA certificate in NGINX](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/217471977-How-to-install-an-Origin-CA-certificate-in-NGINX)
- [Creating and managing certificates with Origin CA](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/115000479507)

Also, `ssl on` is deprecated, [instead](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51703160/5362795), use `listen 443 ssl;`.

Comment: How does this work with universal ssl is there a way to download the edge certificate and key or what