# nginx the "ssl" directive is deprecated, use the "listen ... ssl"

Tags: macos, ssl, nginx, configuration, homebrew

After NGINX upgrade to `v1.15.2` starts getting the warning.

`nginx: [warn] the "ssl" directive is deprecated, use the "listen ... ssl" directive instead in /usr/local/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/confid-file-name:8`

Where the 8th line is `ssl on;`

how I can solve this?

Comment: I had both `listen ... ssl` and `ssl on`, now seems `ssl on` is no more require

Answer (score 313, accepted):

Edit your `listen` statement from:

```
listen 443;
```

to

```
listen 443 ssl;
```

and comment out or delete :

```
# ssl on;
```

then check `nginx -t` again.

Comment: reloading nginx config with `service nginx reload` or other commands depending on your operating system might be necessary

Comment: search for missing `ssl` in all your config fies with `grep "443;" /etc/nginx/sites-available/*
`